# Psql: peer authentification failed WSL2

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed PostgreSQL on my Linux WSL2, all worked good except when i tried to Connect to the database : i Received this errore, failed peer authentification for "postgres" user.

But nothing works.

Have you got an idea?

Thanks

All i tested as a solution :

-Modify the pg_hba.conf

- modify port number
- modify the ip listen

Comment: Look in the log file to see why it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Open your pg_hba.conf file again and change this line

`local   all             postgres                                peer`

to

`local   all             postgres                                md5`

save the file and then restart postgres using `sudo service postgresql restart`

Comment: Ok i will try, what's the difference between peer and md5 ?

Comment: The `peer` method means postgres will trust the identity (authenticity) of the UNIX user. And therefore will not ask for a password.
But md5 means it will always ask for a password, and validate it after hashing with MD5.

Comment: So if i understood well , the method peer Is used only if the user have no password.

Comment: In the peer method, Postgresql will verify the user's identity by checking the operating system and grant the user access without asking for a password